# Event listener is lost after showing again the node

Tags: jquery, event-listener

I've got a code prepared in these two fiddles (pretty similar):

- http://jsfiddle.net/N29rU/1/ - This works
- http://jsfiddle.net/N29rU/2/ - This doesn't work

What I'm trying to do (as you probably figured out) is to show a `select` which will pop up only when user clicks <kbd>edit</kbd>. When something is selected then I want to hide this `select` node and show link to for edits again. I want it to hide the `select` even if nothing changed, so that's why I used event `click` instead of `change`.

Now about my problem. Why is event listener being removed after I click edit, then chose something, then click edit again. Now when I want to chose something the event listener isn't there (checked in Chrome dev tools).

Please note that I'm having the `$(s)` variable as the select, and I'm not re-initiating it anywhere.

---

**Pasting the code**

**HTML**

```
<span id="text">Some text</span> <span>(<a href="#" id="show_select">edit</a>)</span>
```

**java script**

```
var data = ["Some text", "Another thing", "Select me ;]"];

var s = $("<select/>");
$(s).hide();
for (var val in data) {
    $("<option />", {
        value: val,
        text: data[val]
    }).appendTo(s);
}
```

**Working version of creating handlers**

```
$('#show_select').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast", function () {
        $("#text").html($(s));
        $(s).fadeIn("fast");
        $(s).on('click', function (e) {
            $(s).fadeOut("fast", function () {
                var selected = $(s).find(":selected").first().text();
                $('#text').html(selected).fadeIn("fast");
                $('#show_select').parent().fadeIn("fast");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**And this one doesn't work after re-clicking**

```
$(s).on('click', function (e) {
    $(s).fadeOut("fast", function () {
        var selected = $(s).find(":selected").first().text();
        $('#text').html(selected).fadeIn("fast");
        $('#show_select').parent().fadeIn("fast");
    });
});

$('#show_select').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast", function () {
        $("#text").html($(s));
        $(s).fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: you know you don't need to do `$(s)` as `s` is already a jQuery object

Comment: Thank you, forgot about that, though I usually do that cause sometimes I might forget to do it when it's actually necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are changing the html so you are updating the dom with a new version of s each time so there won't be any events bound to this new version of s.  If you just attach the s to the dom once, you can fade in and out without the need to re-attach the event and it will also be a bit better performance wise:

```
var data = ["Some text", "Another thing", "Select me ;]"];

var s = $("<select/>");
var text = $("#text");
s.hide();
for (var val in data) {
    $("<option />", {
        value: val,
        text: data[val]
    }).appendTo(s);
}

s.insertAfter(text);

s.on('click', function (e) {
    s.fadeOut("fast", function () {
        var selected = s.find(":selected").first().text();
        text.html(selected).fadeIn("fast");
        $('#show_select').parent().fadeIn("fast");
    });
});

$('#show_select').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast", function () {
        s.fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/N29rU/6/)

Comment: Thanks, it seems it works :) On some browsers this `click` event doesn't let me chose from select (click is triggered when I'm clicking on select to chose, not after I actually chose something). Do you have an idea how to prevent this?

Comment: I would just use the `change` event but also have a cancel button in case they want to hide it again

Comment: Ok, I also have trouble displaying it inline. How to make `fadeIn` to `inline`, instead of `block`?

Comment: Nvm I found out myself :) `s.fadeIn("fast").css("display","inline-block");`